# Sections duplicating when adding new cells to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a tableview with self-sizing cells in two sections: Ingredients and Steps. When I alternate adding cells and I elect to add a 6th cell to the ingredients section the steps section header gets duplicated and the new ingredient cell is added below that new steps header. Obviously, this isn't what I want. I've checked my index paths and data source and it looks like the data is going into the correct positions so I'm not sure what the source of the issue is. I created an example of the behavior in this GitHub project: https://github.com/amos-nistrian/dynamic-textView.

MainViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol ButtonCellDelegate: class {
    func shouldAddCellInSection(section: Int)
}

protocol ExpandingCellDelegate: class {
    func updateCellHeight(_ indexPath: IndexPath, comment: String)
    func updateArray(_ indexPath: IndexPath, text: String)
}

class MainViewController: UITableViewController, ExpandingCellDelegate, ButtonCellDelegate {

    var steps = [String]()
    var ingredients = [String]()

    let redColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.12, blue:0.14, alpha:1.0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none // remove lines between cells
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false // remove highlighting when selecting a cell

    }


    //////* tableview delegate stuff below here *///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        var headers : [String] = ["Ingredients", "Steps"]
        return headers[section]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

        if let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
            header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
            header.backgroundView?.backgroundColor  = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.35)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch(section) {
        case 0:
            return ingredients.count + 1 // plus one for the button
        case 1 :
            return steps.count + 1 // plus one for the button
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }


    // To enable self-sizing table view cells
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    // To enable self-sizing table view cells
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let section = indexPath.section
        let row = indexPath.row

        switch (section) {

        case 0:
            if (row == 0) {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Button Cell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCell

                cell.delegate = self as ButtonCellDelegate

                cell.button.setTitle("+ Ingredient     ", for: .normal)

                cell.btnInSection = section
                cell.button.tag = 0

                return cell
            } else {

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Picker Text View Cell", for: indexPath) as! PickerTextViewCell

                cell.delegate = self as ExpandingCellDelegate

                cell.cellIndexPath = indexPath
                print("index path is ",indexPath)
                print(cell.textView)
                cell.textView.text = ingredients[row-1]

                return cell
            }

        case 1:
            if (row == 0) {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Button Cell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCell

                cell.delegate = self as ButtonCellDelegate

                cell.button.setTitle("+ Step     ", for: .normal)


                cell.btnInSection = section
                cell.button.tag = 1

                return cell
            } else {

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Text View Cell", for: indexPath) as! TextViewCell


                cell.textView.text = steps[row-1]
                cell.cellIndexPath = indexPath
                cell.delegate = self as ExpandingCellDelegate
                //cell.delegate = self
                return cell
            }

        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Text View Cell", for: indexPath) as! TextViewCell
            return cell
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Adds a new cell to the table and data source
    func shouldAddCellInSection(section: Int) {

        // Update the data source
        if (section == 0) {
            ingredients.append("")
        } else {
            steps.append("")
        }

        let row = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
        print(row)
        print(section)

        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)


        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: ExpandingCellDelegate

    // update the table view cell height
    func updateCellHeight(_ indexPath: IndexPath, comment: String) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }

    // update the data source on key press
    func updateArray(_ indexPath: IndexPath, text: String) {
        let row = indexPath.row-1
        let section = indexPath.section

        if (section == 0) {
            print("Appedning [", text , "] to ingredients[",row,"]")
            self.ingredients[row] = text
        } else {
            self.steps[row] = text
        }
    }

} //EOC
```

PickerTextViewCell

```
import UIKit

class PickerTextViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {


    let greyTextColor = UIColor(red:0.47, green:0.47, blue:0.44, alpha:1.0)
    let lightGreyBackgroundColor =  UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.93, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0)
    let darkerGreyBackgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.77, green:0.77, blue:0.77, alpha:1.0)

    var delegate: ExpandingCellDelegate!
    var cellIndexPath: IndexPath!

    @IBOutlet weak var textHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! {
        didSet {
            textView.backgroundColor = darkerGreyBackgroundColor
            textView.textColor = greyTextColor
            textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.textView.delegate = self
    }


    // hide the keyboard when the user presses done on the keyboard
    // also resizes the textview
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        //print("Content Height \(self.textView.contentSize.height) ")
        //print("Constraint is", self.textHeightConstraint.constant )

        if(self.textView.contentSize.height < self.textHeightConstraint.constant) {
            self.textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        } else {
            self.textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        }

        if (text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }

        self.delegate.updateArray(self.cellIndexPath, text: textView.text)
        self.delegate.updateCellHeight(self.cellIndexPath, comment: textView.text)

        return true
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }

    // hide the keyboard if the user taps somewhere else
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.backgroundColor = lightGreyBackgroundColor
        textView.textColor = greyTextColor
        textView.resignFirstResponder()

        self.delegate.updateArray(self.cellIndexPath, text: textView.text)
    }

} // EOC
```

TextViewCell

```
import UIKit


class TextViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    let greyTextColor = UIColor(red:0.47, green:0.47, blue:0.44, alpha:1.0)
    let lightGreyBackgroundColor =  UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.93, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0)
    let darkerGreyBackgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.77, green:0.77, blue:0.77, alpha:1.0)

    var delegate: ExpandingCellDelegate!

    var cellIndexPath: IndexPath!

    @IBOutlet weak var textHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
            label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! {
        didSet {
            //textView.backgroundColor = darkerGreyBackgroundColor
            textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
            textView.textColor = greyTextColor
            textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.textView.delegate = self
    }

    // hide the keyboard when the user presses done on the keyboard
    // Also resizes the textview
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        print("Content Height \(self.textView.contentSize.height) ")
        print("Constraint is", self.textHeightConstraint.constant )

        if(self.textView.contentSize.height < self.textHeightConstraint.constant) {
            self.textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        } else {
            self.textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        }

        if (text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }

        self.delegate.updateArray(self.cellIndexPath, text: textView.text)
        self.delegate.updateCellHeight(self.cellIndexPath, comment: textView.text)
        return true
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }

    // hide the keyboard if the user taps somewhere else
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.backgroundColor = lightGreyBackgroundColor
        textView.textColor = greyTextColor
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        self.delegate.updateArray(self.cellIndexPath, text: textView.text)
    }

} // EOC
```